# Custom Data Refresh in Microsoft Power BI

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I have a data source connected to to a dashboard that needs to refreshed without actually opening the power bi account. Currently I am able to figure out the powershell script that help me do it from my powershell promt.

The request is something like this

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/DATASET_ID/refreshes" -Method "POST" -Headers @{"Sec-Fetch-Mode"="cors"; "Authorization"="Bearer XXXXXXXXXXTOKENXXXXXXXX"} -ContentType "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

Now the Token gets expired after sometime and I again need to open the power bi website to get the new token.
Is there a way for generate token locally without actually open the website? i tried using Login-`PowerBI` in `Powershell` to get token but is there any other way also.

Answer (score 3):

you need to get a new token each time or get the refresh token from the API. I have tested getting token everytime and I never have a problem. Check my code here to complete your powershell:
https://github.com/ibarrau/PowerBi-code/blob/master/PowerShell/RefreshPowerBi.ps1

Remember you can always install an On Premise Data Gateway to solve this for you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped a lot but implementing your solution needs me to click on a login popup windows every time I run the code, is there a way around which just execute everything in one go?

Comment: Hi, it shouldn't be that way. Are you sure you add $myCred param?
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $myCred

That is for login without a pop up

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you want to refresh a dataset with PowerShell, but without prompting for credentials. In this case, you can store them in the script itself and do something like this:

```
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile

$password = "xxxxx" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "xxxxx@yyyyy.com" 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'groups/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/datasets/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/refreshes' -Method Post

Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount
```